# How do I get POST data without knowing the id?

Tags: php, post

I have a script that prints out divs in a loop. I need each one to have a submit button to POST data that's specific to that div.

How do I get the ID of the post so I can submit it to the database?

HTML in PHP echo ($t is incremented for each loop):

```
<form id="foo'.$t.'">
<input id="bar'.$t.'" name="bar" type="text" value="'.$link.'" />

<input type="submit" value="Report as broken" >
</form>
```

I tried to get the id of the post by treating it like an array or using var_dump, but was unsuccessful.

PHP script:

```
if ($_POST) {
// prepare
        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reports (link) VALUES (?)");

// set parameters
        $a = isset($_POST) ? $_POST : null;

// bind
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $a);

// run
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: There ara many ways do that. For example. you can add hidden input with it's value to form - `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">` and then use it into php like `$_POST['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden field with post id:

```
<form id="foo'.$t.'">
    <input id="bar'.$t.'" name="bar" type="text" value="'.$link.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="Some value" />
    <input type="submit" value="Report as broken" >
</form>
```

On server side you can do something like:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE reports SET link = ? WHERE id = ?"); // or post_id

// set parameters
$link = $_POST['bar'];
$id = $_POST['post_id'];

// bind, I presume your id is number so we pass `i` as argument
$stmt->bind_param("si", $link, $id);

// run
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Adding `bar'.$t.'` to name and the value in the html then changing `$link = $_POST['bar'];` to `$link = $_POST[$id];` got it working for my loop. Thanks!

Comment: It's redundant, if you print $_POST you will see that there are only two items (maybe 3 with button).